# Proccessor is busy all the time

Tags: system-monitor, boinc

I don't really remember when the laptop first started to experienced this problem but the problem is when I open my laptop, I don't know how or why, it is like the laptop is starting to make a dozens of hard calculations.
once I just opened it waited for minutes, without doing something, and it happened again, the laptop is getting warmer and warmer, and fans are starting to make it cooler.
the only tip I can give you guys is I was using BOINC once. but than I moved it to another computer and uninstalled boinc from my laptop. so maybe I could not uninstall it properly and it is still running somewhere in core or something...
thanks advance.

I have:
Intel Core 2 Duo CPU T5450 1.66Ghz x 2***
Intel 965GM x86 MMX SSE2***
32 bit***
Ubuntu 14.04*
here is a random screenshot from system monitor:

[image]

Comment: run `top` in terminal to see what's goin on, what is eating the %

Comment: hey yes I did it you were right! BOINC is there! thanks so very much buddy, we re have completed the half of solution, but I remember that I have uninstalled Boinc, and just checked it right now. it is not installed, so how can it still eat the proccessor?
I think I have to search for "how to delete stuffs permenantly"
any idea for that?
and thanks agai

Comment: you're welcome, you shoud've run: `sudo killall boinc` and then `sudo apt-get remove --purge boinc*`

Comment: hey johnnyEnglish, we just did it :) . I run them and then restart the computer, now the proccessors are normal again :) . 
thanks so very much again nd again

Comment: you're welcome! keep it up :-) I wrote complete guide as an answer, that you can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we solved the problem with help of `top` command this way:

```
sudo killall boinc

sudo apt-get remove --purge boinc*

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade

sudo apt-get autoremove
```